# Exception Handling using throws

Tags: android, exception

This method having Nullpointer Exception in some case , i am using throws to catch this exception, but it does not comes in catch , i am i doing something wrong ???

**Method:-**

```
void soundAtPlayOneForssahAnimation() throws NullPointerException{
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                releaseResource();
                mp_button_Click = (MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.forssah_button_clicked_sound_points));
                mp_button_Click.start();
                mp_button_Click.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.stop();
                        mp.reset();
                        mp.release();
                        mp_button_Click = null;
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 100);

        //wait for .7s to match the duration
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                releaseResource();
                mp_button_Click = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.coupon_rotation_sound_thick_tope_five_seconds);
                mp_button_Click.start();
            }
        }, 700);

        //wait for the coupon rotation finished
        couponRotationFinishedMusicHandler = new Handler();
        couponRotationFinishedMusicHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                releaseResource();
                mp_button_Click = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.coupon_rotation_finished_sound_arcade_reveal);
                mp_button_Click.start();
                couponRotationFinishedMusicHandler = null;

            }
        }, 6500);

        //wait for the timer start

        timerCountMusicHandler = new Handler();
        timerCountMusicHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                releaseResource();
                mp_button_Click = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.timer_count_sound_quiz_thinking);
                mp_button_Click.start();
                timerCountMusicHandler = null;
            }
        }, 7300);


        //wait for the timer till 5sec remaining
        warningTimerCountMusicHandler = new Handler();
        warningTimerCountMusicHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                warningTimerCountMusic = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.warning_timer_sound_second_countdown);
                warningTimerCountMusic.start();
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //releaseResource();
                        if (warningTimerCountMusic != null) {
                            warningTimerCountMusic.release();
                            warningTimerCountMusic = null;
                            if (mp_button_Click != null) {
                                mp_button_Click.release();
                                mp_button_Click = null;
                                warningTimerCountMusicHandler = null;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, 5900);
            }
        }, (sessionTimeOut + 2) * 1000);
    }
```

**This way i am calling it :-**

```
try {
        soundAtPlayOneForssahAnimation();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**My problem is it does not came in catch block**

**Log:--**

> 03-09 15:18:36.180 26446-26446/com.awicompany.forssah
>   E/UncaughtException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke
>   virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources
>   android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                  at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:1007)
>                                                                                  at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:990)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.awicompany.forssah.ui.fragments.GetDiscount_Tutorial$22.run(GetDiscount_Tutorial.java:2799)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
>                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 03-09
>   15:18:36.180 26446-26822/com.awicompany.forssah I/System.out:
>   (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false 03-09 15:18:36.180
>   26446-26822/com.awicompany.forssah I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static:
>   isSBSettingEnabled false 03-09 15:18:36.180
>   26446-26780/com.awicompany.forssah D/FA: Logging event (FE): _ae,
>   Bundle[{_o=crash, _sc=HomeActivity, _si=-7309909218007751274,
>   timestamp=1489061916190, fatal=1}] 03-09 15:18:36.200
>   26446-26780/com.awicompany.forssah V/FA: Using measurement service
>   03-09 15:18:36.200 26446-26780/com.awicompany.forssah V/FA: Connecting
>   to remote service 03-09 15:18:36.430
>   26446-26446/com.awicompany.forssah E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main
>                                                                           Process: com.awicompany.forssah, PID: 26446
>                                                                           java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                               at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:1007)
>                                                                               at android.media.MediaPlayer.create(MediaPlayer.java:990)
>                                                                               at
>   com.awicompany.forssah.ui.fragments.GetDiscount_Tutorial$22.run(GetDiscount_Tutorial.java:2799)
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
>                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
>                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                               at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Comment: What does your title have to do with your question? Also, you need to provide the stack trace from the crash.

Comment: ahh..sorry that was my mistake for the tittle..thanks,

Comment: It looks like when one of your `Runnable`s executes, `getActivity()` is returning null. This is presumably in a `Fragment`, so you'll have to figure out why that `Fragment` is not attached to its `Activity` at that point. Or provide more info here.

Comment: yes man, this happen when i replace this fragment with other while runnables are executing..you understood it man..please help me...

Comment: Well, you're scheduling at least one `Runnable` for upwards of 7 seconds in the future. You can't be performing a transaction before then, or that'll happen. If you really need to schedule `Runnable`s like that, and actually let them run, it'd be safer to have the `Activity` handle them. If, on the other hand, you don't need those to run once you've removed/replaced the `Fragment`, then just make sure to remove them from the `Handler`s before performing the transaction; e.g., with the `removeCallbacks()` method.

Comment: Yaa thanks dude i got it...